# My prefix is man, my suffix is sharp

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is man.
>   My suffix is sharp.
>   My infix is man.
>   The whole is hard.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could be

> adamantine

My prefix is man.

> Adam - first man

My suffix is sharp.

> Tine - a sharp, projecting point or prong, as of a fork.

My infix is man.

> Man - man

The whole is hard.

> adamantine - too hard to cut, break, or pierce.

Comment: Oof, too fast! I just found it myself :)

Comment: @Avi, I found it and never typed so fast.:)

Comment: Aww, you're too good :)  Just to clarify, when you say you "found" it, do you mean you found it somewhere else on the internet? Because I did come up with it myself.

Comment: @Earlien, I found a rot13(n znayl jbeq sbe "uneq" hfvat n gurfnhehf) then dismantled it mentally and silently went, "This works, go, go, go," to myself. No worries.